# windowbuilder xwt design MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte of UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder, xwt

The problem is:
When we are trying to use russian characters in xml-attributes in .xwt file (label text for instance) WindowBuilder design view crashes with error:

com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.

It seems, that xml parser crashes because of the file encoding.

Comment: This might be a good time to make that an answer or delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. WindowBuilder passes IOUtils.toInputStream(xwt_file_content) to XWTParser. XWTParser expects UTF8 encoded stream, but your Eclipse IDE uses default system encoding. Add JVM argument -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 to eclipse.ini.